# How to get Scapy using adaptive ping with fragmented packets

Tags: ping, intervals, scapy, icmp

Is there any way to use adaptive ping option with Scapy? I need to send ICMP packets with flood interval for testing purposes.

Ping tool is not an option, because has adaptive ping yes, but cannot be send fragmented packets (except with -s option specifying bigger size than MTU for the interface) - however I am interested not in to send all the fragments, just some of them, it is why Scapy tool can do that but not ping.

Comment: Is the adaptive ping option similar to the logic described on the [ping man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)? Just trying to make sure I understand what you want.